# You must set the singleton 'Umbraco.Core.Persistence.SqlSyntax.SyntaxConfig'

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to use the Umbraco ContentService in an external MVC application.

In my controller:

```
var contentService = new ContentService();
var document = contentService.GetById(idofdocumenthere);
```

I put my umbraco connectionstring in the web.config file with  `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient`.

This is the error I get after running this code:

```
You must set the singleton 'Umbraco.Core.Persistence.SqlSyntax.SyntaxConfig' 
to use an sql syntax provider

Parameter name: SqlSyntaxProvider
```

I also checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443778/umbraco-v6-deploy-to-production-server-getting-db-exception-content-and-media-t), but this didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't instantiate a new ContextService, use the ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.

Comment: You mean: `ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService`, but ApplicationContext.Current is always null. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, I meant .current!  Fixed it above :-)  It can't be null if you are running in a webcontext.  If it's null, the webapplication didn't boot correctly!  ApplicationContext.Current when IIS launches the website.